# Check if string contains a hashtag and then change hashtag color

Tags: iphone, string, parsing, ios5, twitter

Im developing an iPhone app that fetches tweets from twitter. I'm doing this through Json and everything is working fine. I'm looking to search each tweet and see if it contains a hashtag and then change the color of that specific tag.

For example  : "This is a tweet #MYTWEET"

So I want "This is a tweet" to be one color and "#MYTWEET" to be a separate color. I know how to search for a hashtag but I can't seem to figure out how to change just the text following.

EDIT:

There is no specific hashtag either, so It needs to be able to change the color of any hashtag that appears.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
NSString *tweet = @"This is a tweet #MYTWEET";

NSArray *words = [tweet componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:tweet];

for (NSString *word in words) {

    if ([word hasPrefix:@"#"]) {

        // Colour your 'word' here
        NSRange matchRange = [tweet rangeOfString:word];

        [attrString addAttribute:kCTForegroundColorAttributeName 
                           value:[UIColor redColor] 
                           range:matchRange]; 
        // Remember to import CoreText framework (the constant is defined there)

    }
}

//Display your attributed string ...
```

Note: If you're wondering how to display the string, here is one nice open source project : https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel

Comment: Do I need to import a framework? Im getting an error for kCTForegroundColorAttributeName.

Comment: @Sean Yes you need to import `CoreText` framework, sorry I forgot to mention

Comment: @Alladinian I am getting warning Incompatible pointer types sending 'const CFStringRef' (aka 'const struct__CFString *const) to parameter of type NSString. I have also included CoreText framework. Do you know what the issue is? Also you have to get rid of the pointer for "matchRange"?

Comment: @Supertecnoboff The error means that you pass a `CFStringRef` instead of an `NSString`. Provided that you use `ARC` you should be able to cast it like this `NSString *aString = (__bridge NSString *)aCFString;` (if the error is regarding the constant you can use `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` as well). Also when using `ARC` do not worry about `matchRange`, it will be released automatically for you. I hope that this makes sense.

Comment: @Alladinian Ok thank you. Also do you know how I can get Xcode to actually apply the colour to a UITextView (NOT a UILabel)? I have tried to use the attributedText property, but it hasn't worked: message_post.attributedText = attrString;

Comment: @Supertecnoboff Actually it should be exactly the same (through the `attributedText` property I mean). You could open a separate question with more details if you think that this doesn't work for you on the `UITextView`.

Comment: @Alladinian Right ok. Yeah I posted on StackOverflow and someone answered. You might want to check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22484780/uitextview-attributed-colour-not-being-applied-ios#22485068

Comment: Note: if that string has a line break just before the hashtag, it will not work. You will need to add the folloing // Trim the whitespaces and returns in string
        var trimmed = string.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n", withString: " ")
        trimmed     = trimmed.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\r", withString: " ")

Comment: Works for me with `attrString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: .red, range: matchRange)`
How ever i don't want it to color the punctuations at the end of #Tag. How do i remove it

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSRange hashLocation = [tweetString rangeOfString:@"#MYTWEET"];
 if  (hashLocation.location == NSNotFound) 
      {
          //do coloring stuff here
      }
```

edit: I think you are looking to color a substring only. This is not possible in the current versions of iOS, but you can do so by creating a label for each color and placing them next to each other so that it reads like a single line of text.

Comment: It can be any hashtag though. Sorry I should of explained better.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an `UILabel` to display the string, you could use **[ActiveLabel.swift](https://github.com/optonaut/ActiveLabel.swift)** which is an `UILabel` drop-in replacement **supporting Hashtags (#), Mentions (@) and URLs (http://)** written in Swift.

[image]

Changing the color of usernames, hashtags and links is as simple as this:

```
label.textColor = .blackColor()
label.hashtagColor = .blueColor()
label.mentionColor = .greenColor()
label.URLColor = .redColor()
```

*Disclaimer: I'm the author of the library.*

Comment: This should also be made for UITextView :)